# How to find quarter first date and last date from current date using laravel

Tags: laravel, date, php-carbon

I am trying to set a start date and end date by the current quarter.

```
        case 'quarter':
            $date =  Carbon::now()->month(Carbon::now()->month-3);
            print_r($date);
            $startDate = Carbon::now()->startOfQuarter(); // the actual start of quarter method
            $endDate = Carbon::now()->endOfQuarter();
        break;
```

output as

```
quarter
Carbon\Carbon Object
(
[date] => 2020-12-04 05:21:08.443008
[timezone_type] => 3
[timezone] => UTC
)
Array
(
[startDate] => Carbon\Carbon Object
(
[date] => 2021-01-01 00:00:00.000000
[timezone_type] => 3
[timezone] => UTC
)

[endDate] => Carbon\Carbon Object
(
[date] => 2021-03-31 23:59:59.999999
[timezone_type] => 3
[timezone] => UTC
)

)
```

How can I use Carbon to determine the current quarter? I.e. I would like to get hold of the date when the quarter started and the date when it ends. and also
I am trying to set a start date and end date by the previous quarter.

```
 case 'quarter':
            $date =  Carbon::now()->month(Carbon::now()->month-6);            
            $startDate = Carbon::now()->startOfQuarter(); // the actual start of quarter method
            $endDate = Carbon::now()->endOfQuarter();
        break;
```

But now I am struggling with how to get the start and end date of the current quarter and previous quarter.

Comment: `$date->quarter` should give you what quarter it is in, if that helps ... if you go to the [docs for carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) and search 'quarter' you will see a lot of properties and methods that should be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = CarbonImmutable::now();
$startCurrent = $date->startOfQuarter();
$startPrevious = $startCurrent->subQuarter();

echo $startPrevious . "\n";
echo $startPrevious->endOfQuarter() . "\n";
echo $startCurrent . "\n";
echo $startCurrent->endOfQuarter() . "\n";
```